# How to refresh layout after animation in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a layout which moves on a specific user action. The layout moves a bit up, but buttons are clickable where they were before animation. How do I update the layout's children onAnimationEnd?

[Here I could not find the answer, but I understood the problems is in how the Android Layout system is build.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217638/android-animation-movement-of-container-does-not-correctly-update-contained-bu)

I tried:

```
popupLayout.requestLayout();
```

And:

```
popupLayout.invalidate();
```

Neither worked. Any other Ideas on how to update the contained buttons?

---

Update

Here is how I do the animation:

```
 Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -0.3f);

    slide.setDuration(300);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    popupLayout.startAnimation(slide);
    // and then the AnimationListener
```

---

Update

I tried to set LayoutParams and it does not work neither.

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    dialogLayout.getWidth(), dialogLayout.getHeight());
            // lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            dialogLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Can you show how you perform the animation? Did you try to set new LayoutParams for these children?

Comment: Updated the question, please take a look

Comment: I tried to set LayoutParams and it does not work neither.

Comment: What are you doing in onAnimationEnd() ? Can you post that code too? Basically, this animation modify drawing coordinates only and after animation layout parameters must be changed. What kind of view is it that you are trying to move?

Comment: That's my question actually, what do I do inside onAnimationEnd() so that the view will update, as I don't need this trigger for anything else now. What I am moving and it works nice, is a LinearLayout containing EditTexts and buttons. So any ideas on what should I do to refresh the Layout?

Answer (score 1):

Inside `onAnimationEnd()` you have to update your layout parameters of the view which you are animating, in your case it's LinearLayout. You have to update view in respect of the parent. If your animated view parent is e.g. RelativeLayout you can call this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) animatedView.getLayoutParams();
//TODO modify params
animatedView.setLayoutParams(params);
animatedView.requestLayout();
```

I think this should work. You can also try calling `requestLayout()` on the parent.

There is also [tutorial on YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UWXqFBF86U&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_XOgcRukSoKKjewFJZrKV0&index=70) about View animations. Chet Haase talks about handling animations including `TranslateAnimation`. I don't have time to watch but maybe you will find there your answer.

**Update**

If you manage successfully set layout params after animation, don't forget to remove line:

```
slide.setFillAfter(true);
```

Remember that animation modify ONLY drawing coordinates relative to the view position. In other words, it creates an offset to original position which has to be reset after animation ends. Method `setFillAfter(true)` skip reseting this offset.

Answer (score 0):

setContentView(rootLayout) will do the job... not working

Comment: this refreshes the whole layout to initial form, but I want the layout to stay where it is at the end of the animation